# How to use macro parameters to declare variables

Tags: c

I am given a few descriptions of macros and I have to define them.

**DECL_LIST( type, name )**

Expands to the declaration syntax for the three variables used in a resizable array implementation,
name_len, name_cap and name (the pointer itself).

**CHECK_CAP( type, name )**
Expands to the code to make sure the resizable array has enough capacity for another element and to
enlarge it if it doesn’t.

**• SIZE( name )**

Expands to an expression for the number of elements currently stored in the array.

**• FOR( var, limit )**

Expands to the first line of a for loop that uses an int variable named var to iterate from 0 up to (but not
including) limit.

**• SWAP( type, a, b )**

Expands to a block of code that swaps the values of two variables a and b of the given type. We need
the type parameter in order to declare a temporary variable that will help swap the values.

The logic is for this sorting function is already there. I just have to use the same logic in the macros in the manipulated function:

```
// Put your macro definitions here.  That should be all
// you need to do to complete this exercise.
#define DECL_LIST(type, name) \
    int name ## _cap = 5;     \
    int name ## _len = 0;     \
    type *name = (type *) malloc(name ## _cap * sizeof(type)); 

#define CHECK_CAP(type, name)                                         \
if ( name ## _len >= name ## _cap ) {                                 \
name ## _cap *= 2;                                                    \
name = (type *) realloc(name, name ## _cap * sizeof(type)); \
}  

#define SIZE(name)    \
sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]) 


#define FOR(var, limit) { \
  int var = 0;  \
for( int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {          \
       var++;           \
}    \
}

#define SWAP(type, a, b)   \
type temp = a; \
   a = b; \
   b = temp; 


int main()
{
  // Make a resizable list.
  DECL_LIST( double, list );

  double val;
  while ( scanf( "%lf", &val ) == 1 ) {
    // Grow the list when needed.
    CHECK_CAP( double, list );

    // Add this item to the list
    list[ SIZE( list ) ] = val;
    SIZE( list ) += 1;
  }

  // Bubble-sort the list.
  FOR( i, SIZE( list ) )
    FOR( j, SIZE( list ) - i - 1 )
      if ( list[ j ] > list[ j + 1 ] )
        SWAP( double, list[ j ], list[ j + 1 ] );

  // Print out the resulting, sorted list, one value per line.
  FOR( i, SIZE( list ) )
    printf( "%.2f\n", list[ i ] );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This was the original main function before it was converted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
// Make a resizable list.
int list_cap = 5;
int list_len = 0;
double *list = (double *) malloc( list_cap * sizeof( double ) );
double val;
while ( scanf( "%lf", &val ) == 1 ) {
// Grow the list when needed.
if ( list_len >= list_cap ) {
list_cap *= 2;
list = (double *) realloc( list, list_cap * sizeof( double ) );
}
// Add this item to the list
list[ list_len ] =val;
list_len++;
}
// Bubble-sort the list.
for ( int i = 0; i < list_len; i++ )
for ( int j = 0; j < list_len - i - 1; j++ )
if ( list[ j ] > list[ j + 1 ] ) {
double tmp = list[ j ];
list[ j ] = list[ j + 1 ];
list[ j + 1 ] = tmp;
}
// Print out the resulting, sorted list, one value per line.
for ( int i = 0; i < list_len; i++ )
printf( "%.2f\n", list[ i ] );
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the compiler output after making some recommended changes:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     SIZE( list ) += 1;
                  ^
sortList.c:50:8: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
   FOR( i, SIZE( list ) )
        ^
sortList.c:22:7: note: in definition of macro ‘FOR’
   int var = 0;  \
       ^
sortList.c:52:18: error: ‘j’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if ( list[ j ] > list[ j + 1 ] )
                  ^
sortList.c:52:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sortList.c:53:15: error: expected expression before ‘double’
         SWAP( double, list[ j ], list[ j + 1 ] );
               ^
sortList.c:29:1: note: in definition of macro ‘SWAP’
 type temp = a; \
 ^
sortList.c:31:8: error: ‘temp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    b = temp; 
        ^
sortList.c:53:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWAP’
         SWAP( double, list[ j ], list[ j + 1 ] );
         ^
sortList.c:56:8: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
   FOR( i, SIZE( list ) )
        ^
sortList.c:22:7: note: in definition of macro ‘FOR’
   int var = 0;  \
       ^
sortList.c:57:29: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     printf( "%.2f\n", list[ i ] );
```

Any suggestions if my current macros are correct? I am kind of confused on the descriptions.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: oops, forgot to include it. Question updated.

Comment: Your macros are wrapped in `{` `}`. You don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You teacher wants you to use [C preprocessor token pasting](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/cpp/Concatenation.html) to create a macro that replaces the code. For example, the first macro would look like this

```
#define DECL_LIST(type, name) \
    int name ## _cap = 5; \
    int name ## _len = 0; \
    type *name = (type *) malloc(name ## _cap * sizeof(type));
```

and would replace this code

```
// Make a resizable list.
int list_cap = 5;
int list_len = 0;
double *list = (double *) malloc( list_cap * sizeof( double ) );
```

Regarding your questions about the `CHECK_CAP` macro, your teacher wants you to replace this code with a macro

```
// Grow the list when needed.
if ( list_len >= list_cap ) {
    list_cap *= 2;
    list = (double *) realloc( list, list_cap * sizeof( double ) );
}
```

but leave this code intact

```
// Add this item to the list
list[ list_len ] =val;
list_len++;
```

Later, you can replace `list_len` with your `SIZE` macro.

Hopefully, this will help you understand why the macro doesn't need to modify `list_len`.

`FOR` should be

```
#define FOR(var, limit) \
    for (int var = 0; var < limit; var++)
```

You need to use braces around `SWAP` because it expands to multiple lines:

```
  if ( list[ j ] > list[ j + 1 ] ) {
     SWAP( double, list[ j ], list[ j + 1 ] );
  }
```

Comment: So, for the second one, how would the macro know if the size of the array needs to be resized? It doesn't know the updated size after insertion of the data.

Comment: It checks the capacity before the insertion: `if ( list_len >= list_cap )`

Comment: But how does list_len get set to the length of the list?

Comment: The `list_len` isn't affected when the capacity is increased.

Comment: In your answer, you used *list for pointer. Shouldn't it be *name since we don't know what the name of the pointer will be?

Comment: You are correct. I fixed it. This is one of the reasons you don't actually want to use macros to replace code: They hide defects. If I use a good editor, it will tell me when I have an unused variable. If I replace the code with a macro, the editor loses it's ability to detect these problems and they are only detectable at run time.

Comment: I update the macros but the compiler is giving me some errors in SWAP that temp is undeclared. There are also some other errors regarding not declaring variables. But from what I see in the code, it seems like everything is declared. The command line errors are listed above.

Comment: `SIZE(name)` should just be `name ## _len`.